# is it possible to "like" facebook fan page directly from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to "like" facebook fan page directly  from iPhone app using graph API?

Answer (score 2):

There is no graph api method to have a user like a page (that would get abused).  The only way would be to embed a Facebook like button inside a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found is to use a `UIWebView` and either load the html portion of the LIKE code, or use an external .html document with the LIKE code. The only issues I have come across in this method is the user usually needs to login unless logged in from MobileSafari.